# How can I transform a PHPMailer connection to Laravel .env?

Tags: laravel, email, phpmailer

I have a situation where an app is sending its mails with PHPMailer and next configuration:

```
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->Host     = 'myhost.dev';
      $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

      $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
      $mail->addAddress($to, $to_name);
      if ($replyTo != '') $mail->addReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName);
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
      $mail->Subject = $subject;
      $mail->Body    = $body;
```

As you can see, SMTP server doesn't require authentication and all is working ok. That's all data I have about the mail server. Now, I need to make the same thing but instead of using PHPMailer I want to implement the sending method of Laravel, but I don't have any authentication credential for setting my .env file.

How can I pass the same configuration to my Laravel development? I've tried many combinations but nothing happens. This was the last one:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=myhost.dev
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@host.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=''
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer has no idea about Laravel, so you need to pass through the information yourself. Laravel provides the `env()` global function to retrieve data from the environment, and you would use it like this:

```
$mail->Host = env('MAIL_HOST');
if (!empty(env('MAIL_USERNAME')) {
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = env('MAIL_USERNAME');
    $mail->Password = env('MAIL_PASSWORD');
}
```

and so on, for any other configuration variables you need. I'm not sure exactly what Laravel package defines the `env` function, but you will need to make sure it's loaded and within scope before calling it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Synchro but implement PHPMailer is not what I'm looking for. I want to replace PHPMailer by Laravels mailing method, but I don't know how to configure my .env file to use it without authentication. Maybe I gave you a bad explanation. Sorry by that. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Perhaps read [the Laravel mail docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail)?